# challenge building jsx in nested loop

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build JSX in a nested loop.  x.Table below is collection of row metadata and each row metadata has a collection of cell metadata.  The final result in render should be a nested div structure which represents div equivalents of rows and cells to render based on x.Table metadata.  I'm having some issues coding this up properly.  Here's some code to provide context but it doesn't quite compile.  What do you recommend?:

```
// create jsx for subtable rows
let subtableRows: JSX.Element[] = [];
let subtableRow: JSX.Element;

// for each table row
x.Table.forEach(x => {
    <div style={{ display: 'table-row-group' }}>
        x.Cells.forEach(y => {
            <div style={{ display: 'table-cell' }}>{y.FieldValue}</div>
        });
        subtableRows.push(
            subtableRow
        )
    </div>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seing more of your code, you can map over your table and create a div for each row:

```
// for each table row
const rows = x.Table.map(x => {
    // you're missing this return here
    return <div style={{ display: 'table-row-group' }}>
        x.Cells.forEach(y => {
            <div style={{ display: 'table-cell' }}>{y.FieldValue}</div>
        });
        subtableRows.push(
            subtableRow
        )
    </div>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When building nested JSX from arrays, you will more often see the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function used to format raw data.

For example to create one row of your table, you would do something like

```
let subtableRow = x.Cells.map(y => {
  return <div style={{ display: 'table-cell' }}>{y.FieldValue}</div>;
});
```

Result

```html
subtableRow = [
    <div style={{ display: 'table-cell' }}>{..}</div>
    <div style={{ display: 'table-cell' }}>{..}</div>
    ...
]
```

The same way, you would build the entire table by nesting `map` calls

```
let subtableRows = x.Table.map(x => {
  return <div style={{ display: 'table-row-group' }}>
    {x.Cells.map(y => {
      return <div style={{ display: 'table-cell' }}>{y.FieldValue}</div>;
    })}
  </div>;
});
```

Be sure not to forget! Between a `<div ..>` and its `</div>`, you are in JSX territory, so you need to use `{}` to input JavaScript code again.